# Droid Binding using CreateBindingSet doesn't work when using OnViewModelSet but setting layout in OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

Tags: mvvmcross

To kind of keeping consistency, as in Touch, we create the layout (from nib or code) in LoadView, and setup all the binding in ViewDidLoad : I thought I would do something similar in Droid. So, I would create and SetContentView on OnCreate, followed by setting the bindings at OnViewModelSet.

That threw me following error

03-29 22:13:13.892 I/mono-stdout( 2447): MvxBind:Warning:  9.53 Failed to create target binding for binding Click for CallCustomerServiceCommand

If I move binding code into OnCreate, it works fine.
If I move SetContentView in OnViewModelSet, it works fine.

I can ofcourse set it all up in one place, but is this the default behavior?

Example view with only one text area and two buttons; all text are coming

```
public class TopupErrorView : BaseView
{
    #region Controls

    private MyLabel PageText;
    private MyButton ButtonCallCustomerService;
    private MyButton ButtonCallPayByPhone;

    #endregion

    #region Setup View

    protected override LinearLayout MainContent(out LinearLayout footer)
    {
        footer = null;

        var content = new StackPanel(this, Orientation.Vertical)
        {
            Spacing = 10,
            SubViews = new View[]
            {
                PageText = new MyLabel(this, "PageText"),
                ButtonCallCustomerService = new MyButton(this, "ButtonCallCustomerService"),
                ButtonCallPayByPhone = new MyButton(this, "ButtonCallPayByPhone")
            }
        };

        return content;
    }

    public new TopupErrorViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (TopupErrorViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    }

    #endregion


    #region All Binding

    protected override void SetupBinding()
    {
        #region Common Section between Platforms

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TopupErrorView, TopupErrorViewModel>();

        set.Bind(PageText).To(vm => vm.PageText).OneTime();
        set.Bind(ButtonCallCustomerService).For(c => c.Content).To(vm => vm.ButtonTextCustomerService).OneTime();
        set.Bind(ButtonCallCustomerService).To(vm => vm.CallCustomerServiceCommand).OneTime();
        set.Bind(ButtonCallPayByPhone).For(c => c.Content).To(vm => vm.ButtonTextPayByPhone).OneTime();
        set.Bind(ButtonCallPayByPhone).To(vm => vm.CallPayByPhoneCommand).OneTime();

        set.Apply();

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Base class:

```
public abstract class BaseView : MvxActivity
{
    private MasterPageControl _masterPageControl;

    #region Abstract

    protected abstract LinearLayout MainContent(out LinearLayout footer);

    protected abstract void SetupBinding();

    #endregion

    #region Handling page events

    protected sealed override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }

    protected sealed override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        _masterPageControl = new MasterPageControl(this);

        LinearLayout footer;
        var contentLayout = MainContent(out footer);

        var layout = _masterPageControl.GetLayout(contentLayout, footer);
        SetContentView(layout);

        SetupBinding();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

so ideally, I would like OnViewModelSet to only have the line SetupBinding()

Comment: Why for the Droid project you set bindings from code? You can easily do it from the layout.

Comment: choper, my above code for View TopupErrorView is 100% identical to Touch version, and almost identical to WP8 (which currently is created from xaml); I prefer it this way: makes it easier for me :D

Answer (score 1):

> I thought I would do something similar in Droid. So, I would create and SetContentView on OnCreate

I suspect that the problem here is that `OnViewModelSet` is called during `base.OnCreate(bundle)` - so the 'following' sequence you are looking for cannot happen - although it's hard to be sure without seeing your code for the 2 methods.

`OnViewModelSet` itself is really just a remnant from mvx v1 - it's not a key method in MvvmCross. Most examples I've seen work directly in `OnCreate` which is fairly analogous to working in `ViewDidLoad` in iOS.

Comment: Update: where do you set `ButtonCallPayByPhone` to a value?